# Issue with jQuery Lights in IE7

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

On the following page: http://westendmediacentre.com/dev/

I am using a jquery popup that pops up either when you click "Login", or when you click "Regster".  When you click either of these, the "lights" dim on the rest of the page, so the popup box is more prominent.

Works fine in IE9, FF, Safari, etc, but in IE7, the "lights" div is appearing above the content, despite the content having a higher z-index.

If you view source on the page, you should be able to see all the code and so forth.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove `position: relative` to .container class. Then assign `position: fixed` to .register-box class, width in percentage (ex: 50%) and `left: 25%`.